# Converting MS to Seconds

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I found this formula to use to turn MS into Seconds but it was written for Excel 2002 and i am using 2010.

```
=CONCATENATE(TEXT(INT(B1/1000)/86400,"hh:mm:ss"),".",B1-(INT(B1/1000)*1000))
```

Here are a few examples of what I am trying to take from MS to Seconds

```
25188
59125
64092
19115
26416
```

I will be honest i am not very good with Excel formulas so any help would be great. I have taken a screen shot of the error that i am getting with the above formula.

[image]

Comment: Are you entering the formula in `cell B1`?

Comment: There are much simpler ways to do this. Just divide by 86400000 (the number of milliseconds in a day) and format result cell as [h]:mm:ss.000 - i.e. with this formula `=B1/86400000`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works fine in Excel 2010.  You just can't put this formula in cell B1.

If you put a number in B1 and this formula in any other cell, it will work.

You're getting a circular reference warning because the formula refers to cell B1, which is the cell the formula is in.

Comment: You're no more an idiot than anyone else here.  We've all been there.

Comment: Yeah i was reading the blog post wrong. Its late on a friday and my brain is spent... Cheers John have a great weekend truly appreciate your help!

Comment: You too. My pleasure!

Answer (score 0):

The code you're using isn't actually correct. For instance, your example of 64092
returns 00:01:04.92, when it should return 00:01:04.092.

This is because you're not padding your milliseconds with zeros, like so:

```
=CONCATENATE(TEXT(INT(B1/1000)/86400,"hh:mm:ss"),".",TEXT(B1-(INT(B1/1000)*1000),"000"))
```

But you're complicating things.

As @barry-houdini points out, it would me much simpler to use:

```
=TEXT(B1/86400000,"hh:mm:ss.000")
```

if you need a text cell for some reason, or just

```
=B1/86400000
```

to get the time in days, setting a custom format for the cell to "hh:mm:ss.000".