# Convert seconds to microseconds in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have time values in seconds 
how to convert values in seconds to microseconds in excel

0.00777
0.00373

the above values are in seconds.
Now i need to convert these values to microseconds
i need below values
7770
3730

Comment: What about multiplying them with 1000?!

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325840/converting-ms-to-seconds

Comment: how to multiply ... i am very new to excel

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of an answer:

The multiplication operator is `*`, so something like `=A1*1000000`

Comment: Multiply By 1000000 for microseconds